# JPA - contains() return false knowing that the object exist in the List

Tags: list, jpa, contains

I have two Classes 'Parent' and 'Child'. Between them there is and Unidirectional Many To Many Association.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PARENT")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idParent;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PARENT_CHILD", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PARENT"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CHILD"))
    private List<Child> Children = new ArrayList<Child>();

    //Getters and Setters ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_CHILD")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idChild;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    //Getters and Setters ...
}
```

Here is the table PARENT_CHILD from the DB :

```
 ----------------------
| ID_PARENT | ID_CHILD |
 ----------------------
| 1         | 1        |
 ----------------------
```

And Here Is My Problem :

```
 //The child with the ID = 1
 Child child   = this.ChildService.one(new Long(1));
 //The parent with the ID = 1
 Parent parent = this.ParentService.one(new Long(1));

 //This gives me "false" and i don't know why ????
 System.out.println(parent.getChildren().contains(child));
 System.out.println(child.getIdChild() + " - " + child.getName()); // output: 1 - BOB
 c = parent.getChildren().get(0);
 System.out.println(c.getIdChild() + " - " + c.getName()); // output: 1 - BOB
```

As You can see, i had the same output but why gives me "false" ??!

**EDIT :** (Solution)
The Problem is i was using using two different sessions to get the children thus leading to two different instances, So i needed to make sure that `childService` and `parentService` are using a single transaction (thx to the annotation `@Transactional`).
-- a big Thanks to @JBNizet

Comment: Do you do that in a single transaction? If you don't, that's expected since you have not defined equals() on Child, and you're using two different sessions to get the children thus leading to two different instances.

Comment: I'm using Spring Data JPA. How to make sure "childService" and "parentService" are using a single transaction??

Comment: By making the method containing the code you posted transactional.

Comment: using the annotation `@Transactional` ??!

Comment: Yes (if annotation transaction handling is enabled in your project, of course).

Comment: **Works like a charm**, but the list `p.getChildren()` contains now duplicated entries knowing that in my database there is only one entry!!

Comment: That's probably because the Child or the Parent has another eagerly fetched toMany association. You should use a Set<Child> instead of a List<Child>.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem with sets rather than lists. The JPA entity hashcode isn't matching itself in the contains() call... not sure why.